# Django - Javascript not working in templates

Tags: javascript, html, django-templates

I am trying to display an input field based on user choice selection. Learning from stackoverflow, I have written the following code:

```
<form action="/register/" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">{% csrf_token %}
<select name="designation" id="designation">
   <option value="faculty">Faculty</option>
   <option value="student">Student</option>
</select>

<div id="students" style="display:none;">
<input type="file" name="uploadFile">
</div>
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
$('#designation').on('change',function(){
    if( $(this).val()==="student"){
    $("#students").show()
    }
    else{
    $("#students").hide()
    }
});
</script>
```

The code does work in https://jsfiddle.net/. However, when I am trying to use it in my django template its not working.(i.e., on selecting 'student' nothing appears). I have the following included as well in my base.html.

```
<script src="{% static 'jquery-3.2.1.min.js' %}"></script>
<script src="{% static 'js/bootstrap.min.js' %}" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

**UPDATE:**
**base.html:** hideshow.js is the script.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
{% load staticfiles %}
{% load static %}
<html lang="en"
      xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/html">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">       

    <link href="{% static 'css/bootstrap-dist.min.css' %}" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="{% static 'css/ie10-viewport-bug-workaround.css' %}" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="{% static 'JS/html5shiv.min.js' %}"></script>
    <script src="{% static 'JS/respond.min.js' %}"></script>
    <script src="{% static 'JS/hideshow.js' %}"></script>


    <link href="{% static 'css/carousel.css' %}" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/bootstrap.min.css' %}" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/bootstrap-theme.min.css' %}" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'css/sampleLogin.css' %}" />
</head>

<body>
{% include "messages_display.html" %}
<br />
{% include "navbar.html" %}

{% block content %}

{% endblock %}
```

**register.html:**

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}

{% block content %}    
<div class="container">
<div class="col-md-12">   
<div class="col-sm-7 col-sm-offset-2">
<h1>{{ title }}</h1><br />        
<form action="/register/" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">{% csrf_token %}
<select name="designation" id="designation">
   <option value="faculty">Faculty</option>
   <option value="student">Student</option>
</select>

<div id="students" style="display:none;">
<input type="file" name="uploadFile">
</div>
</form>

{% endblock content %}
```

Please help.

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Comment: Please write the code on the document ready block, I hope it will definitely work for you.

Comment: This code works. Please include a full description of what doesn't work.

Comment: @Nathan P, Bharat soni, Hassam Imam, I have tried to describe the problem.

Comment: Hi @surajitM I am too facing this issue did you get any solution for this?

Comment: Hey!, did you ever got it to work? I have exactly the same issue, everything in the code is prefect, but it just doesn't show or work the way it's supposed to

Answer (score 2):

First you have to include jquery.min.js file in html file. Then you have to keep js code in **$(document).ready(function()**.then your code will work

```
 <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#designation').on('change',function(){
                console.log($(this).val());
                if( $(this).val()==="student"){
                    $("#students").show()
                }
                else{
                    $("#students").hide()
                }
            });
        });
</script>

<select name="designation" id="designation">
   <option value="faculty">Faculty</option>
   <option value="student">Student</option>
</select>

<div id="students" style="display:none;">
<input type="file" name="uploadFile">
</div>
```

Comment: tried your way. included both jquery.min.js and the script in base.html. extended base.html to the current html. Still no joy and I have no clue how to resolve the issue. :(

Comment: are you using django framework ? or in which framework you are working?

Comment: using django 1.11

Comment: No error. Just on changing to 'Student', the upload file does not appear.

Comment: Then i guess something is wrong while extended html file or script. or you can write script in separate js file and include that js file in current html file. and your html code should be on same current html file.

Comment: I have updated my questions with base.html and register.html for your reference. Please check.

Comment: include jquery.min.js file in base.html file