# Generating Django HTML template with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, django, ajax, django-templates, jspdf

I used this function to download the PDF version of HTML template, but it didn't work, here is the function:

```
<script>
        function getPDF() {

            var HTML_Width = $(".canvas_div_pdf").width();
            var HTML_Height = $(".canvas_div_pdf").height();
            var top_left_margin = 15;
            var PDF_Width = HTML_Width + (top_left_margin * 2);
            var PDF_Height = (PDF_Width * 1.5) + (top_left_margin * 2);
            var canvas_image_width = HTML_Width;
            var canvas_image_height = HTML_Height;

            var totalPDFPages = Math.ceil(HTML_Height / PDF_Height) - 1;


            html2canvas($(".canvas_div_pdf")[0], {
                allowTaint: true
            }).then(function(canvas) {
                canvas.getContext('2d');

                console.log(canvas.height + "  " + canvas.width);


                var imgData = canvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg", 1.0);
                var pdf = new jsPDF('p', 'pt', [PDF_Width, PDF_Height]);
                pdf.addImage(imgData, 'JPG', top_left_margin, top_left_margin, canvas_image_width, canvas_image_height);


                for (var i = 1; i <= totalPDFPages; i++) {
                    pdf.addPage(PDF_Width, PDF_Height);
                    pdf.addImage(imgData, 'JPG', top_left_margin, -(PDF_Height * i) + (top_left_margin * 4), canvas_image_width, canvas_image_height);
                }

                pdf.save("HTML-Document.pdf");
            });
        };
    </script>
```

It works only when the HTML snippet doesn't contain Django tags or variables, here is an example where it worked:

```
<button onclick="getPDF()" id="downloadbtn" style="display: inline-block;"><b>Click to Download HTML as PDF</b></button>
<div class="canvas_div_pdf" style="margin-left:100px;">
 <h1>title</h1>
<p> Content.</p>
</div>


<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf/1.3.3/jspdf.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://html2canvas.hertzen.com/dist/html2canvas.js"></script>
```

And here is where it didn't work:

```
<button onclick="getPDF()" id="downloadbtn" style="display: inline-block;"><b>Click to Download HTML as PDF</b></button>
    <div class="canvas_div_pdf" style="margin-left:100px;">
     <h1>{{qr.title}}</h1>
    <p> {{qr.content}}</p>
    </div>
    
    
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf/1.3.3/jspdf.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://html2canvas.hertzen.com/dist/html2canvas.js"></script>
```

The button doesn't work, there are the same actions in the console, with and without using Django variables in the HTML snippet.

And for Django, I used a simple function to render the template:

```
...
def index(request):
    ...
    qr = Article.objects.all()
    context["qr"] = qr[0] #for testing
    return render(request, "index.html", context)
```

Note: I tried many other options like pdfkit, or wkhtmltopdf, and they are worst, some of them worked but didn't load the Django variables too.
I'm interested in generating the template with JavaScript.

Comment: could you write the error you are getting?

Comment: The error is I got nothing, nothing happened when I click on the button.

Comment: I had a similar problem once, you could try wrapping your script inside a $(document).ready(function() and import jquery before your script?

Comment: I really have no idea about JavaScript, can you be more precise?

Comment: like the answer to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45231022/django-javascript-not-working-in-templates

Comment: Thanks, it worked, but there is no images in the pdf :(